# Laravel 3: View doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I've just inherited a Laravel 3 site which works on a custom CMS. The CMS output is rendered through a theme folder at the / level so my folder structure looks like:

```
-application
-bundles
-laravel
-public
-storage
-theme
  -errors
  -layouts
    -partials
```

I've made a search controller within '/application/controllers' and I want to create my view for the output in the '/theme/layouts' folder with the other template files. When I've worked with Laravel before, my views are all within '/application/views' and I can specify my view with:

```
public $layout = 'layouts.default';
```

..which would use '/application/views/layouts/default.blade.php'

How can I get my controller to render the view using my '/theme/layouts/searchTemplate.php' file and pass in the search data from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to put these files in a separate folder you should probably use bundles (see [docs](http://three.laravel.com/docs/bundles)).

However, a quick and dirty solution is to add a hook in the view loader event (application/start.php):

```php
Event::listen(View::loader, function($bundle, $view)
{
    if($bundle == 'theme') {
        return View::file('application', $view, Bundle::path('application').'theme');
    }

    return View::file($bundle, $view, Bundle::path($bundle).'views');
});
```

You can then make views like:

```php
View::make('theme::layouts.default');
```

which will load the file "*application/theme/layouts/default.blade.php*".

Answer (score 0):

In your application folder, there is a folder called 'views'
You have to create the default.php in applications/views/layouts/

With 'layouts.defaults' it search in the views folder to a folder that will be called layouts.

So the complete folder for 'layouts.default' would be: ./application/views/layouts/default.php

Edit: answer is not relative anymore

Comment: In the question, I ask how I can specify a view outside of application/views/layouts folder. Specifically at /theme/layouts